# Fall back to translate 'someItem' with root locale?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, internationalization

In i18n.ts:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import uk from '../locales/eng';
import ru from '../locales/ru';

const i18n = createI18n({
fallbackLocale: 'en',
legacy: false,
missingWarn: false,

warnHtmlMessage: false,
locale: 'ru',
messages: {
    uk,
    ru
}
});

export default i18n;
```

`

I have all the keys and it translates perfectly fine, but I am getting warning for all keys:
Fall back to translate 'Balance' with root locale.
Not found 'Balance' key in 'ru' locale messages.
I also tried silentTranslationWarn: true.

Comment: Tro to be more precise and update your questions. Display the error too.

Comment: Did you have a 'Balance' key in your `'../locales/ru'` object ?

Comment: yes, I do. Translation works fine, the only problem is that, I am receiving this warning in cosole